# Fatal Python error when using PyQt5 in a virtual environment

Tags: python, anaconda, pyqt5, python-venv

I have made a virtual environment with venv, and used pip to install PyQt5. When I try any program that uses PyQt5, i get the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
```

I am using Python 3.6.0, Anaconda 64 bit, and have installed PyQt5 with pip (version 4.20), on Windows 7 64 bit.

MWE:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
```

I have confirmed this does work on my regular install.

Answer (score 0):

you should install it using this command:

```
conda install pyqt
```

And import it like:

```
import pyqt
```